# Вставка перед абзацами в word через vba тега <p>

Tags: vba, ms-word

```vb
For Counter = 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
    Set Paragraph = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(Counter)
    With Paragraph.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "^l"
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    ParagraphString = Paragraph.Range.Text
    Paragraph.Range.Text = "<p>" & Trim(ParagraphString) & "</p>"
Next Counter
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

```
<p></p>Привет я первый абзац, а ты какой? Привет я первый абзац, а ты какой? Привет я первый абзац, а ты какой? первый <b>абзац</b>, а ты какой? первый абзац, а ты какой? первый абзац, а ты какой? первый абзац, а ты какой? первый абзац, а ты какой? первый абзац, а ты какой? первый абзац, а ты какой? первый абзац, а ты какой?
<p></p>
```

Такой результат приходит

Comment: Я конечно догадываюсь, что ты пытаешься обернуть текст абзаца в тег `<p>`, но ты этого не пишешь. Перефразируй нормально вопрос согласно правилам ресурса. Должно быть четко и ясно написано, какая задача стоит, что ты сделал, что не получилось, какой помощи ждешь.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ParagraphHandler()
    For Each Para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        With Para.Range
            ' Проверяем что в абзаце есть текст.
            ' Можно не проверять, тогда пустые отступы тоже будут в тегах <p></p>
            If Len(.Text) > 1 Then
                .InsertBefore "<p>"
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                .MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
                .InsertAfter "</p>"
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]